# segmentation fault while copying a file

Tags: c++

I have below simple code , but when I  compile and run with GCC on unix, I got segmentation error. Is it because file naming or copying one file to others. Any help appreciated..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void copy(char *infile, char *outfile) {
    FILE *ifp; /* file pointer for the input file */
    FILE *ofp; /* file pointer for the output file */
    int c; /* character read */
    /* open i n f i l e for reading */
    ifp = fopen (infile , "r" );
    /* open out f i l e for writing */
    ofp = fopen(outfile, "w");
    /* copy */
    while ( (c = fgetc(ifp)) != EOF) /* read a character */
        fputc (c, ofp); /* write a character */
    /* close the files */
    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);
}

main() 
{
copy("A.txt","B.txt");
}
```

Comment: `main` should return `int`, but I don't see any other problem jumping out at me.  Where does your debugger say the error is?  Did you check that `ifp` and `ofp` are valid pointers?

Comment: That ain’t C++ code …

Comment: BTW, your code above is really C language, so, you should be remove the "using namespace std" and use #include <stdio.h> and #include <stdlib.h>

Answer (score 1):

The code which you have posted is correct

```
 ifp = fopen (infile , "r" );  //will return NULL if file not there 

 while ( (c = fgetc(ifp)) != EOF)
```

The moment you are using ,  Here is a possibility if you do not have A.txt file in your current directory then you will get segmentation fault.

Comment: That line will just return `NULL` is there's no input file.  The fault will happen sometime later when it is used.

Comment: @CarlNorum yes absolutley correct. Modified my answer. thanks for pointing this.

Answer (score 1):

IF A.txt does not exist, the value of ifp will be NULL (0).  Then, this function call will segfault.

```
fgetc(ifp)
```

So, change your code to check for NULL on the file opens (each file), for example:

```
ifp = fopen (infile , "r" );
if (ifp == NULL) {
    printf("Could not open %s\n", infile);
    exit(-2);
}
```

You may have to add this include also at the top of your file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `copy(const char* infile, const char* outfile)` in arguments to avoid unnecessary warnings.

Also **your files may not be in the current directory in which you are executing code**. So give **complete path** to your file.

Comment: thanks guys. I solved my problem. I have just put main and A.txt and B.txt in the same file and problem is solved.Gangadhar were right. I am not sure but A.txt were not in the same directory before cuz I lost the program I could not find now but I had compile it with code:: blocks in windows then I  carried it to unix environment and because main exe were under /bin/debug unde code::blocks (not the same directory with A.txt ) the problem ocuured. Thanks all anyway